# Covert 2006 Trailblazer from 4WD to 2WD

Tags: 4wd, trailblazer, front-differential

My front differential is make noise because of a leak. I have been watching videos how to disengage the front differential and make it a 2 wheel rear wheel drive only ( I don't need 4 wheel drive). Have anyone done this or any reason it should not work? I have a 2006 Trailblazer LT Sport Utility 4-Door 4.2L 256Cu. In. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the propshaft to the front will remove the 4x4.

But is the noise severe? If so then unless there are locking front hubs that can be disengaged the internals will still rotate and that may also lead to failure.

Removing the differential may be the way forward, but then the shafts to either hub have to be removed and that will depend on the design of the front hubs themselves - ok if they are fully floating.

It may be easier to get the front axle / suspension from a 4x2 and deal with it that way.

It is probably easier to sort the front axle / diff as standard compared to the above options.

Comment: Thanks Mike, after some more research it looks like the front hub for a 4WD and a 2WD on Trailblazers (2002-2009) are exactly the same. The bearings are part of the hub and can not be changed hub needs to be replaced if bearings go bad.  Is that want meant  by saying "OK if they are fully floating" ?